# Counting occurances in numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have following two arrays of the same dimension of tags and tag categories. I want to group tags according to categories and count occurrences of tags.

As you can see tags can share same categories ('world', 'hello').

I know this can be easily done with loops but I'm sure numpy has some nifty ways of doing it more efficiently. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
# Tag category
A = [10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 10, 20, 10, 20, 20]
# Tags
B = ['hello', 'world', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'world', 'you', 'how', 'hello', 'hello']
```

Expected result:

```
[(10, (('hello', 1), ('are', 1), ('you', 1), ('world', 2))), (20, (('how', 1), ('you', 1), ('hello', 2)))]
```

Comment: [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) may be more suitable for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for this.

Here we are going to use the integers from `A` as key of the outer dict and and for each inner dict we'll use the words from B as key, and their value will be their count.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
>>> for k, v in zip(A, B):
        d[k][v] += 1
```

Now `d` contains(I converted it to normal dict, because its output is less confusing):

```
>>> pprint({k: dict(v) for k, v in d.items()})
{10: {'are': 1, 'hello': 1, 'how': 1, 'world': 2, 'you': 1},
 20: {'hello': 2, 'how': 1, 'you': 1}}
```

Now we need to loop through the outer dict and call `tuple(.iteritems())` on the outer list to get the desired output:

```
>>> pprint([(k, tuple(v.iteritems())) for k, v in d.items()])
[(10, (('world', 2), ('you', 1), ('hello', 1), ('how', 1), ('are', 1))),
 (20, (('how', 1), ('you', 1), ('hello', 2)))]
```

Comment: I'm not following this part `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))` can you explain in more detail. thanks!

Comment: @marcin_koss This creates a nested dictionary structure, where the outermost keys will have a dictionary as value and the inner dictionary will have integer value(default 0).

Comment: Got it, thanks. Now, what would be the best way to also order tag tuples by count?

Comment: @marcin_koss You can replace `v.iteritems()` with `sorted(v.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1))`, where `itemgetter` is `operator.itemgetter`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks you! I will look into Pandas as well.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's been mentioned, here's a way to aggregate the values with Pandas.

Setting up a DataFrame...

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': A, 'B': B})
>>> df
    A      B
0  10  hello
1  10  world
2  20    how
3  10    are
4  10    you
5  10  world
6  20    you
7  10    how
8  20  hello
9  20  hello
```

Pivoting to aggregate values...

```
>>> table = pd.pivot_table(df, rows='B', cols='A', aggfunc='size')
>>> table
A      10  20
B            
are     1 NaN
hello   1   2
how     1   1
world   2 NaN
you     1   1
```

Converting back to a dictionary...

```
>>> table.to_dict()
{10: {'are': 1.0, 'hello': 1.0, 'how': 1.0, 'world': 2.0, 'you': 1.0},
 20: {'are': nan, 'hello': 2.0, 'how': 1.0, 'world': nan, 'you': 1.0}}
```

From here you could use Python to adjust the dictionary to a desired format (e.g. a list).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> A = np.array([10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 10, 20, 10, 20, 20])
>>> B = np.array(['hello', 'world', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'world', 'you', 'how', 'hello','hello'])
>>> [(i,Counter(B[np.where(A==i)]).items()) for i in set(A)]
[(10, [('world', 2), ('you', 1), ('hello', 1), ('how', 1), ('are', 1)]), (20, [('how', 1), ('you', 1), ('hello', 2)])]
```

Comment: This won't scale well as you're doing this in quadratic time.

Answer (score 0):

> but I'm sure numpy has some nifty ways of doing it more efficiently

**and you're right!** Here is the code

```
# convert to integer
category_lookup, categories = numpy.unique(A, return_inverse=True)
tag_lookup, tags = numpy.unique(B, return_inverse=True)

statistics = numpy.zeros([len(category_lookup), len(tag_lookup)])
numpy.add.at(statistics, [categories, tags], 1)

result = {}
for category, stat in zip(category_lookup, statistics):
    result[category] = dict(zip(tag_lookup[stat != 0], stat[stat != 0]))
```

For explanation see [numpy tips and tricks](http://arogozhnikov.github.io/2015/09/29/NumpyTipsAndTricks1.html). This gives expected answer:

> {10: {'are': 1.0, 'hello': 1.0, 'how': 1.0, 'world': 2.0, 'you': 1.0},
>   20: {'hello': 2.0, 'how': 1.0, 'you': 1.0}}

I shall admit, this is not the most clear way to do this (see pandas solution), but it is really fast when you have huge amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

**Python: NumPy Made Counting Occurrences Easy:**

#import NumPy

> import numpy as np
>
> arr = np.array([0,1,2,2,3,3,7,3,4,0,4,4,0,4,5,0,5,9,5,9,5,8,5])
> print(np.sum(arr==4)) #Test occurance of number 4
>
> unique, counts = np.unique(arr,return_counts=True)
> print(unique,counts)

**[0 1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9] [4 1 2 3 4 5 1 1 2]**

The above is the output